# What is the complexity cost of adding X-Ray instrumentation in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I've started using AWS Synthetics **Canaries** with the **Active Tracing** option on, and correct me if I'm wrong, it's not very useful without **nodejs code instrumentation** like if I was making AWS SDK calls:

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const awsSdk = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));
```

and at the very least to trace errors in downstream:

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https'));
```

Is in place.

My concern is, that adding X-ray will increase the weight of complexity of the functions. Unless this instrumentation is somehow toggled off when not in use?

Answer (score 3):

`const awsSdk = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));` enables instrumentation of *all* AWS SDK clients, which actually shouldn't affect the complexity of any of your functions.

You may add "complexity" if you decided to enable instrumentation *per client* (note that you can only use one or the other):

```js
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
...
var ddb = AWSXRay.captureAWSClient(new AWS.DynamoDB());
```

Active tracing enabled on a Lambda function, will only allow one thing - [tracing of requests that don't have a tracing header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html). If you've enabled X-Ray tracing in a service that invokes your function e.g. API Gateway or calling the Lambda via an instrumented EC2 instance, you do **not** need active tracing. The service doing the tracing will sample incoming requests according to your settings & then add the tracing header where needed. Tracing AWS SDK calls just provides more *granularity* in the service map.

---

**However, to answer your question, the AWS X-Ray SDK has two modes: manual and automatic.**

It is in automatic mode by default (e.g. in a Lambda function), however, you *can* toggle the manual mode on the X-Ray SDK, like so.

```js
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
...
AWSXRay.enableManualMode();
```

This however will require you to pass around segment references as shown [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#manual-mode-examples).

For example, to [capture function calls](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#capturing-function-calls), this is one example:

```js
import { S3, PutObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
const s3 = AWSXRay.captureAWSv3Client(new S3({}), subsegment);

await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: keyName,
  Body: 'Hello!',
}));
```

---

**This *then* becomes very complex in my opinion, and I would just recommend turning it on *per client* as opposed to *"per function"* if you're worried about too much data.**